# How I bind a Instance of a Class without the @Default qualifier

Tags: java, junit5, jboss-weld

I'm using weld-junit to using CDI in my tests.

How do I inject a instance of a Class that I created before? Like I can do in Binder that extends from AbstractBinder.

My Test Class:

```
@EnableWeld
public class VersionProcessTest {

    @WeldSetup
    public WeldInitiator weld = WeldInitiator
            .of(VersionProcess.class);

    @Test
    public void GetSolversVersion() throws DirectoryNotFoundException {

        weld.event().select(FileService.class).fire(new FileService("workDir", "solverTest"));

        String version = weld.select(VersionProcess.class).get().execute();
        assertThat("should return version string", version, instanceOf(String.class));
    }
}
```

My Binder:

```
public class TestBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(new FileService("test")).to(FileService.class);
        bind(SolverVersionApiServiceImpl.class).to(SolverVersionApiService.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I really looking for was to declarate a Produces for my Injection Class.

For that I add the Produces declaration for FileService (injected class):

```
@RequestScoped
@Produces
FileService fileService = new FileService("workDir", "solverTest");
```

And change the WeldInitiator declaration to set the class that contains the @Produces annotation, in my case was the TestClass, so:

```
@WeldSetup
public WeldInitiator weld = WeldInitiator.from(VersionProcess.class, VersionProcessTest.class).activate(RequestScoped.class).build();
```

And voilá it's working the dependency injection for VersionProcess class.